# GetEventLog - How to have 'Message' property expanded in one line poweshell

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell I am using this cmdlet:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational  | Where {  ($_.ID -eq "25" -or  $_.ID -eq "21") -and ($_.TimeCreated -gt [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-2))} | Select TimeCreated, Message
```

I need to get all information in one line. but it display the information like this.

```
'2020/07/07 13:12:18                     リモート デスクトップ サービス: セッシ...'
```

Comment: Isn't all information in one line? Please clarify a bit more.

Comment: I believe the issue can be connected with the Message property. `Message` is a string containing a block of information. It looks like a dictionary but is not. Try to append `... | Format-List`. Like this you should see the whole Message block.

Comment: i want full message in one line.

Comment: This is where you should be creating psCustom Objects.